# Ajax request for a timer update gapping

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, timer

I have a table in my DB that contains the time to start/stop a timer, and in my index I got a  to display the time left in seconds.
And I have this ajax request every 1 second

```
function timer(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "timeleft.php",
    success: function(msg){
        $('#timeleft').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

Problem is: the timer doesn't show the time left properly, sometimes it only update 5 to 5 seconds(120, 115, 110) which update taking 5 seconds and sometimes it does like this 120, 115, 114, 109, 108, 103(5 seconds stuck then 1 second update OK)
The most strange thing is when I press f12 on chrome to see what's going on, the timer starts to work like a charm. And the timeleft.php request are shown taking 200~400ms to load.
There's no other function or anything in the same page that has any 5 seconds interval. 
I have no clue why is that, help me please.
Thank You very much

EDIT: The problem really is not in the javascript. It's the timeleft.php that is not updating well.

```
<?php
@include_once ("set.php");
$game = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");
$r = fetchinfo("starttime","games","id",$game);
if($r == 2147483647) die("120");
$r += 120-time();
if($r < 0) $r = 0;
echo $r;
?>
```

When the "starttime" is set, and I access this page in the browser and keep pressing f5 it is not updating in real time.
What could it be? Thank You

Comment: Ajax is nothing but **asynchronous JavaScript and XML**. You do not have control over the execution and response time. I would suggest you to get the `timeleft` on page load and play with it using `setInterval`

Comment: But the timeleft keeps changing, its like a game time counter. Before the task starts, the timer shows 120 seconds left and stays this way until some task is started, as soon as its started then a bot script outside the website updates the table setting the end time in timestamp for 120 seconds from current time, then it starts displaying the timeleft and when it comes down to 0 the div displays 120 seconds again until another task is started. Those tasks are activated buy how many user are in the "game". It's a gambling website and I bought the source.

Comment: Once page is loaded, fetch the remaining time and keep on updating it on intervals..

Comment: But when it gets to 0 what will happen?
Then after that when the time is set on the database again the timer should start counting again from 120

Comment: Is time () itself skipping around or is your script skipping after applying your logic to it.

Comment: Try $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] this will give the time at the start of the http:// request.

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] is also "gapping" sorry my bad english. It goes like: xxxxxxxxx01, xxxxxxxxxxx05, xxxxxxxxxxx06, xxxxxxxxxxx10....
Not sure what's going on. If i use javascript Date().getTime() function and use javascript to compare, will it work? Or Date().getTime() is different for every timezone? If so, how can I force javascript to use timestamp on server time to all client running the script? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You must take into account for the fact that the Ajax request has processing time of it's own, which could be anywhere from 200~400ms. Overtime, this will skew the timeleft greatly. This is why polling timer's that rely on databases are not a good fit when exactness is a requisite.

Comment: Exactly. you should always minimize server requests and seeing how you know that if working correctly the response should alway decrement by 1 second you should keep this client side.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you approaching this like this. In my opinion the proper way to do this would be to grab the expire time of the timer in one ajax request then count down with your javascript.

```js
    var timerEnds=0;

    function startTimer(){
      if(timeDelay!=null || timeDelay != undefined){
        clearInterval(timeDelay);
        clearInterval(checkTime);//IF USING 5 SECOND SYNC
        }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "timeleft.php",
        success: function(msg){
            timerEnds=msg;
            var timeDelay= setInterval(updateTimer,1000);
            
          
            var checkTime= setInterval(startTimer,5000);//Include this line to sync your expire time with server every 5seconds
            }
        });
    }

    function updateTimer(){
      
           remainingTime=timerEnds-(Date.now()/1000);
         
          if(remainingTime>-1){
              remainingMinutes=Math.floor(remainingTime/60);
           remainingSeconds=Math.floor(remainingTime-ticketMinutes*60);
           $("timer").html(remainingMinutes+":"+remainingSeconds);
            }else{
              //USE THE FOLOWING TO UPDATE EXPIRE TIME AFTER TIME EXPIRES
              remainingTime=0;
               remainingMinutes=Math.floor(remainingTime/60);
           remainingSeconds=Math.floor(remainingTime-ticketMinutes*60);
           $("timer").html(remainingMinutes+":"+remainingSeconds);
              startTimer();
              }
      }
```

Of course you will need to edit your php to give a timestamp of the expire time of the timer. But this will save your bandwith and should prevent latency from effecting your timing

Comment: My timer is not a one time thing. I have a jackpot website for a game items, 120 seconds shows in the timer untill the second guy goes in the pot, then the bot(which is externally set) puts in the database: starttime=  <current_time> then the timeleft.php does this:


<?php
@include_once ("set.php");
$game = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");
$r = fetchinfo("starttime","games","id",$game);
if($r == 2147483647) die("120");
$r += 120-time();
if($r < 0) $r = 0;
echo $r;
?>

Comment: Then after the 120 seconds are up you can fetch the timer again from the database. Or you can request the updated expire time less frequently while decrementing your timer through javascript. The whole idea is minimizing your use of AJAX requests because unless your on a local area network you just simply are not going to be able to get 1 ajax request per second without it gapping.

Comment: Just realized that doing this

echo time();

Is only updating the time 5 to 5, not 1 to 1.. No matter how many times i load the page the time increases 5 to 5 seconds, any idea?